# C# checkbox

Tags: c#

I have 3 check boxes in each row of 8 total rows. I want to have the third checkbox in each row to get checked only when the first two checkboxes are unchecked. I do not want to write a checkRow() method for each row.

What is the best way to go about it?

```
private void checkRow()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        var arraylist = new[] { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 };
        if (checkbox1.Checked || checkbox2.Checked)
        {
            arraylist[2].Checked = false;
        }
        else
            arraylist[2].Checked = true;
    }
}


private void checbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkRow();
}

private void checbox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkRow();
}

private void checbox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkRow();
}
```

In response.

```
private void checkRow()
{
    var arraylist = new[] { checkEdit1, checkEdit2, checkEdit3 };
    var arraylist1 = new[] { checkEdit4, checkEdit5, checkEdit6 };
    var arraylist2 = new[] { checkEdit7, checkEdit8, checkEdit9 };
    var array = new[] { arraylist, arraylist1, arraylist2 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //if checkedit1 or checkedit2 is checked the checkedit3 should not be checked
        if (array[i]....Checked || array[i]....Checked)
        {
            arraylist[i]...Checked = false;
        }
        else
            arraylist[i]...Checked = true;
    }
}
```

I was trying to do something like this so that I dont have to write the checkRow() for each row

Comment: You know, you're not using i in your for loop...

Comment: Yes, I figured that was what you were getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using a `DataGridView` or other way of organizing them into logical rows, why don't you do the following:

Store the checkboxes in an array so you have easy access to them.

```
  CheckBox[,] checkArray = new CheckBox[8,3]...
```

Store the row index in the `Tag` property of the first and second checkboxes.

```
  checkBox01.Tag = 0;
  checkBox02.Tag = 0;
  checkBox11.Tag = 1;
  checkBox12.Tag = 1;
```

Have all the first and second checkboxes point to the same event handler:

```
  checkBox01.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(aCheckBox_CheckedChanged);
  checkBox02.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(aCheckBox_CheckedChanged);
  checkBox11.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(aCheckBox_CheckedChanged);
  checkBox12.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(aCheckBox_CheckedChanged);
```

In the event handler, you now know exactly which check box to update and no longer have to loop:

```
  private void aCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int rowIndex = (int)((CheckBox)sender).Tag;
      checkArray[rowIndex,2].Checked = !(checkArray[rowIndex,0].Checked || 
                                         checkArray[rowIndex,1].Checked);
  }
```

You can also do this using string lookups with the checkbox name, but it is surely slower and is a pain to refactor later if you choose to rename the checkboxes.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the same method as the handler for all three delegates.

```
chkbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkbox_CheckedChanged);
chkbox2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkbox_CheckedChanged);
chkbox3.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkbox_CheckedChanged);

private void chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```